# Where from/to install my.cnf for percona db

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mysql, performance-tuning

I am new to Percona db. I just realized that by default percona does not have a my.cnf file installed. I found this from,

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/673844

In case, I need a my.cnf with default settings for percona where do I get it from and where do I place it. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Percona, as you mentioned, does not install a default `my.cnf` deliberately. Their MySQL builds aim for high performance and since there is no one-size-fits-all configuration that would be suitable for everyone, they don't install one on purpose. It's up to the administrator to decide which configuration options will suit this installation and the given workload better.

However Percona ships with a lot of examples, each example based on the expected workload size. The configurations differ mostly by the size of the buffers and the caches allocated. There are the following configuration examples:

1. my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf (apporpriate for **4GB+ memory** installation with **InnoDB** and **heavy queries**)
2. my-huge.cnf (appropriate for **2GB+ memory** installation dedicated MySQL)
3. my-large.cnf (appropriate for **512MB memory** installations dedicated MySQL server)
4. my-medium.cnf (appropriate for **128MB memory** installations, small DB along with web server)
5. my-small.cnf (appropriate for **64MB memory** installation, sporadic use of the database)

The memory above is the memory which is (expected to be) allocated to the MySQL process alone.

You will find the sample configurations in:

```
/usr/share/mysql
```

You should simple choose one and copy it to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
$ sudo cp -i /usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The configuration alone will rarely make it or break it. Most of the time the configuration depends on the type of the application and the queries you run, as well as the expected workload. And if you reach the size or requirements of `my-huge.cnf` then you probably know what you are doing or you should start reading books and articles online on how to optimize MySQL!

*The path to the configuration is based on the prebuilt deb binaries of [Percona 5.5.24 for Ubuntu  12.04 (Precise)](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.5/Percona-Server-5.5.24-26.0/deb/precise/x86_64/)*